# Laravel get public url for file stored in storage public folder

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-storage

On Windows I have Xampp. My application is in Anuglar and Laravel 8
I add files to folder public in storage folder.
Configuration in `filesystem.php`:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

In `.env` file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8082/prftbx-crm-api/public
```

File in public folder:

```
 Directory of C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-api\storage\app\public

06/25/2021  11:01 AM    <DIR>          .
06/25/2021  11:01 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/26/2021  10:57 PM                14 .gitignore
06/25/2021  11:01 AM               510 381787c3ad1442cc882ee427e93af805.txt
```

In Laravel I return url using method:

```
$fileDTO->filePath = Storage::url($fileEntity->file_name);
```

And in view I have address:

```
/storage/381787c3ad1442cc882ee427e93af805.txt
```

When I type url in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8082/crm-api/public/storage/381787c3ad1442cc882ee427e93af805.txt
```

I get `404`, file not found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First run following command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

then you can

```
http://localhost:8082/storage/381787c3ad1442cc882ee427e93af805.txt
```

keep app url as

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8082
```

As document says

> The public disk included in your application's filesystems
> configuration file is intended for files that are going to be publicly
> accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and
> stores its files in storage/app/public.
>
> To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a
> symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public. Utilizing
> this folder convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one
> directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero
> down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.
>
> To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan
> command:
>
> php artisan storage:link Once a file has been stored and the symbolic
> link has been created, you can create a URL to the files using the
> asset helper:

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk